# How to get a crisp, exact color match for lossless screen-cast?

Tags: ffmpeg, screen-casting, linux

## Background

Recording a screen-cast (no audio) in Xubuntu Linux. The following image shows a side-by-side comparison of the video (left) versus the desktop (right):

[image: Lossless encoding]

The screen-cast is recorded using:

```
ffmpeg -r 30 -f x11grab -s $WIN_GEO -i :0.0+$WIN_XY -vcodec huffyuv -preset ultrafast -qp 0 output.mkv
```

Here, `$WIN_GEO` stores the browser dimensions (1030x794) and `$WIN_XY` has the browser location (1020x221).

```
$ cat /etc/issue
Ubuntu Trusty Tahr (development branch) \n \l
```

## Problem

The colours in the video differ from the colours shown on the desktop, resulting in a slightly blurry playback. I have read that this could be due to conversion between RGB and YUV colours.

## Question

How do you record a desktop video (screen-cast) that when played back (e.g., using mplayer, VLC, or ffplay) results in an *exact* match to the original desktop colours and crispness?

## Related

Relevant pages:

- http://www.unixuser.org/~euske/vnc2swf/
- http://technically.us/pictures/test.html
- http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1392026
- https://askubuntu.com/questions/347574/how-to-do-screencasting-desktop-recording-with-high-quality-audio-and-video
- http://step4wd.com/2012/08/03/recording-screencast-in-ubuntu-linux/
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/73622/how-to-get-near-perfect-screen-recording-quality
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65970/washed-out-colours-with-screencast-software-but-not-screenshot-on-ubuntu-all-ve
- https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/How%20to%20grab%20the%20desktop%20%28screen%29%20with%20FFmpeg
- http://rayslinux.blogspot.ca/2012/04/capturing-linux-desktop-via-command.html

Comment: What is the final context that is going to require such exacting playback?  If you plan on using the video on the Internet, it will need to be transcoded and compressed at some point which is going to result in far greater alteration and loss of clarity.  You are most likely correct about the color space shift, but I can't find any details about how to make sure ffmpeg is using huffyuv in RGB mode (which it does support).

Comment: huffyuv in rgb should be lossless by default, is FFV1 lossless here?  If not, then the input is somehow bad...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Capturing the video frames in XWD format then converting to PNG yields results that are *almost* pixel perfect when encoded with ffmpeg.

Install [xvidcap](http://xvidcap.sourceforge.net/):

```
mkdir -p $HOME/dev
cd $HOME/dev
svn checkout svn://svn.code.sf.net/p/xvidcap/code/trunk xvidcap-code
cd xvidcap*
./autogen.sh
LIBS="-ldl -lX11 -lXext" ./configure --prefix=/usr/local
make && sudo make install
```

Capture stills at 25 frames per second:

```
mkdir -p $HOME/video
cd $HOME/video
xvidcap --fps 25 --quality 100 --cap_geometry 1024x768+768+288 --file out%05d.xwd
```

This creates a series of X Windows capture files inside `$HOME/video`. Convert the files to PNG format using [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/) then combine into a video:

```
for i in out*.xwd; do convert -define png:color-type=2 $i $(basename $i .xwd).png; done
ffmpeg -i out%05d.png -c:v huffyuv -preset veryslow -qp 0 -qscale:v 0 output.avi
```

An example script:

```
echo "Click window to capture..."

INFO=$(xwininfo -frame)
WIN_GEO=$(echo $INFO | grep -oEe 'geometry [0-9]+x[0-9]+' | grep -oEe '[0-9]+x[0-9]+')
WIN_XY=$(echo $INFO | grep -oEe 'Corners:\s+\+[0-9]+\+[0-9]+' | grep -oEe '[0-9]+\+[0-9]+' | sed -e 's/\+/,/' )

OUTPUT_DIR=$HOME/video

echo Capturing to $OUTPUT_DIR...
rm -rf $OUTPUT_DIR
mkdir -p $OUTPUT_DIR
cd $OUTPUT_DIR

WIN_XY=$(echo $WIN_XY | tr , +)

xvidcap --fps 25 --quality 100 --cap_geometry $WIN_GEO+$WIN_XY --file out%05d.xwd

# Convert captured images to PNG format
echo "Converting XWD to PNG..."
for i in out*.xwd; do convert -define png:color-type=2 $i $(basename $i .xwd).png; done

ffmpeg -i out%05d.png -c:v huffyuv -preset veryslow -qp 0 -qscale:v 0 output.avi
```

This creates a high-quality video that looks sharp with [VLC](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/index.html), can be edited in [OpenShot](http://www.openshotvideo.com/), and uploaded to various video hosts. Playback with MPlayer yields slightly fuzzy and off-coloured results.